# Pdf containing Jupyter cding and stuff back to Jupyter

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, pdf-generation, jupyter, pdf-conversion

A friend of mine converted his jupyter notebook into a pdf and sent that to me. I need to convert the pdf back into Jupyter  notebook. Is it possible & how?? TIA